# Unable do deserialize XDocument

Tags: c#, deserialization, linq-to-xml, xmlserializer, xml-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize XDocument to a class that contains an array/list. The problem is this code fails to do so, I always get a `Response` class without any Inventory items (not null, but count = 0)

Here is my test method:

```
public void GetObj()
{
    var xe = new XElement("Inventory");
    var xe2 = new XElement("Id", "23");
    xe.Add(xe2);

    var list = new List<XElement>();
    list.Add(xe);
    list.Add(xe);

    var doc = new XDocument(new XElement("Response", list));

    var obj = doc.Deserialize<Response>();
}
```

And here are my extension methods and models:

```
public static class XDocumentExtensions
{
    public static T Deserialize<T>(this XDocument doc)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        using (var reader = doc.Root.CreateReader())
        {
            return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }

    public static XDocument Serialize<T>(this T value)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        XDocument doc = new XDocument();
        using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, value);
        }

        return doc;
    }
}

public class Response
{
    public List<Inventory> Inventory { get; set; }
}

public class Inventory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to diagnose a problem with XML deserialization is to construct an instance of your model in memory and serialize it, then compare the output XML with the desired input.  Thus, if I do:

```
Console.WriteLine(new Response { Inventory = new List<Inventory> { new Inventory { Id = 23 } } }.Serialize() );
```

The output XML is:

```
<Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Inventory>
    <Inventory>
      <Id>23</Id>
    </Inventory>
  </Inventory>
</Response>
```

As you can see, there's an extra level of nesting of `<Inventory>` elements.  It is there because, by default, `XmlSerializer` serializes collections with an outer container element element named after the serialized member (here `Inventory`) as well as an element for each item, named (by default) after the item type (here also `Inventory`).  Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kNk9yr).

If you don't want this, you need to add [`[XmlElement]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) to `public List<Inventory>` like so:

```
public class Response
{
    [XmlElement]
    public List<Inventory> Inventory { get; set; }
}
```

Now `Inventory` will be serialized without the outer container element, and so your deserialization code will succeed.  Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yYDuFq).

(Alternatively, you could construct your `XDocument` with the requisite extra level of nesting.)

Comment: really usefull tip!